# Pushing items on a dictionary in Python

Tags: dictionary, python-2.7

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
diction = {1: {'Type': 'Cartoon', 'Time': 8:00},
           2: {'Type': 'Movie', 'Time': 19:30},
           3: {'Type': 'Show', 'Time': 16:00}}
```

So it's a dictionary containing dictionaries. I've read that a dictionary cannot be sorted so I'm trying to dynamically add these inner dictionaries to diction as they are created. And I need them sorted by time. Earliest time first. So for example, when it comes time for the program to add the inner dictionary of type show to the dictionary, it adds it inbetween cartoon and movie based on their time values.
Basically, is there any way to push items into the middle of a dictionary? I know you can pop them off but I can't find any push equivalent

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you used a list of dictionaries instead?

Comment: Not when it comes to actually using the dictionaries for their purpose. But maybe I could convert the dictionary to a list, sort it, and try converting it back again?

Comment: That actually might be the best thing to do.  You might end up doing more programming then you need to.

Comment: "Not when it comes to actually using the dictionaries for their purpose" - what is the difference? Is `diction` very large?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Junuxx suggested: "Wouldn't it be better if you used a list of dictionaries instead?"
why you don't try with:

```
diction = [{'Type': 'Cartoon', 'Time': 8:00},
           {'Type': 'Movie', 'Time': 19:30},
           {'Type': 'Show', 'Time': 16:00}]
```

List are ordered, dictionary, as you said, are not because they are meant to be "explored" with a hash key.

Now you can simply retrive your inner dictionay with diction[0], diction[1] etc, and you will be sure that it will give the exact element in the list, ordered by append time

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I had actually gone ahead and coded this out as Junuxx suggested. Works great!